# OverlayPanel shows arrow on the wrong side (PrimeVue)

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I am working with [overlay panels](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/overlaypanel) in the [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/) framework, but there is an odd issue I can't fix.

As shown in the demo page the arrow is on the left side:

[image]

However I need it on the right:

[image]

After some google-searching I was able to find [this bug report](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7220) but I am for some reason unable to find a solution to this.

Does anybody know how to move the arrow to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no property documented to show the arrow on the right side. But you can try to overwrite the styles manually. The arrows are applied as `:before` and `:after` elements of the `.p-overlaypanel` container. You need to define more specific styles to push the Arrows to the right. This can be done, for example, as follows:

```css
<OverlayPanel class="my-panel">
</OverlayPanel
...

.p-overlaypanel.my-panel:before {
  right: 10px !important;
}

.p-overlaypanel.my-panel:after {
  right: 10px !important;
}
```